# how to capture effective date in which a value change in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I start with a file in which I have daily data from a group of people, and I would like to captures when one value of one column change if it did change

The dataframe's structure looks like the one below:

| id | name | startdate | filedate | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | 10-12-2019 | 24-04-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | Sta | 10-12-2019 | 25-04-2021 | 0.5 |
| 1 | Sta | 10-12-2019 | 26-04-2021 | 0.5 |
| 1 | Sta | 10-12-2019 | 27-04-2021 | 0.9 |
| 2 | Danny | 20-03-2020 | 24-04-2021 | 1 |
| 2 | Danny | 20-03-2020 | 25-04-2021 | 1 |
| 2 | Danny | 20-03-2020 | 26-04-2021 | 0.3 |
| 2 | Danny | 20-03-2020 | 27-04-2021 | 0.3 |
| 3 | Elle | 14-08-2020 | 24-04-2021 | 1 |
| 3 | Elle | 14-08-2020 | 25-04-2021 | 1 |
| 3 | Elle | 14-08-2020 | 26-04-2021 | 1 |
| 3 | Elle | 14-08-2020 | 27-04-2021 | 1 |

my goal is to set the first effective date of a person to the startdate and then set the effective date the filedate when the value change.

getting a dataframe like this one:

| id | name | effective date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | 10-12-2019 | 1 |
| 1 | Sta | 25-04-2021 | 0.5 |
| 1 | Sta | 27-04-2021 | 0.9 |
| 2 | Danny | 20-03-2020 | 1 |
| 2 | Danny | 26-04-2021 | 0.3 |
| 3 | Elle | 14-08-2020 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comapre for not equal values per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and replace first values per names by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), last `rename` and remove column:

```
df = df[df['value'].ne(df.groupby('name')['value'].shift())].copy()

df['startdate'] = df['startdate'].mask(df.duplicated('name'), df['filedate'])

df = df.rename(columns={'startdate':'effective date'}).drop('filedate', axis=1)
print (df)
   id   name effective date  value
0   1    Sta     10-12-2019    1.0
1   1    Sta     25-04-2021    0.5
3   1    Sta     27-04-2021    0.9
4   2  Danny     20-03-2020    1.0
6   2  Danny     26-04-2021    0.3
8   3   Elle     14-08-2020    1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer @jezrael, I am validating the results on my data but it seems to work like charm. I have some problems though but it is more relevant to my data source. Thanks again!